# Determining the Big-O growth rate of this function

Tags: math, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I cannot determine how to determine the growth rate of these type of functions.

```
void A(int n){
 int i=1, s=1;
 while(s<=n){
   i++;
   s=s+i;
   cout<<"hi";
   }
}
```

It is given that this is O(sqrt(n)) but I cannot figure how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the values of s across each iteration, you'll see that it goes 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, etc. These numbers are called the triangular numbers and are numbers of the form k(k+1)/2 (it's common to prove this as an exercise in induction.)

The loop stops running as soon as s exceeds n. On iteration k, the value of s is k(k+1)/2, so you can count up the number of iterations by solving for k in k(k+1)/2. Try doing that and seeing what you find. Does that explain the square root?

Comment: Thanks. This helped.